# No puedo crear una nueva tabla en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

No puedo integrar una nueva tabla en mi base de datos porque cuando la agrego a mi aplicación de `C#` me aparece el siguiente error:

> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
>   Error     Error 75: Parte de clave: 'EsReverso' para el tipo
>   EstadisticasConciliacion no es válida. Ninguna parte de clave debe
>   aceptar valores
>   NULL. KonciliaEntities    D:\Projects2017\PopularTx\KonciliaATM\KonciliaEntities\KonciliaTx.edmx  2434

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Este es el script que estoy usando para crear la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Canje]( [IdCanje] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, [NombreCanje] nvarchar NOT NULL, [CodigoCanje] [int] NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_Canje] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [IdCanje] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Adicional esta es el `script` de la tabla `EstadisticaConcicliacion`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EstadisticasConciliacion](
    [ConjuntoProcesos] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [NombreProceso] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [FechaCompensacion] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [FechaProceso] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [Dispositivo] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [NoTx] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Valor] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [EsReverso] [bit] NULL,
    [TipoTx] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Autorizador] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Adquiriente] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TipoMovimiento] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Aprobado] [bit] NULL,
    [EsConsulta] [bit] NULL,
    [EsConsistente] [bit] NULL,
    [TipoTarjeta] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EstadisticasConciliacion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FechaCompensacion] ASC,
    [FechaProceso] ASC,
    [Dispositivo] ASC,
    [NoTx] ASC,
    [TipoTx] ASC,
    [Autorizador] ASC,
    [Adquiriente] ASC,
    [TipoMovimiento] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Revisa tu modelo de la base de datos, si no me equivoco, te esta diciendo que en la tabla `EstadisticasConciliacion` en la columan `EsReverso` tiene una restriccion de llaves (PK, FK), la cual no puede ser nula.

Comment: Si colocas la estructura de tu tabla, es mas facil para la comunidad saber que puede estar fallando.

Comment: "Ninguna parte de clave debe aceptar valores NULL" ¿Has colocado algún breakpoint?

Comment: El error le aparece cuando trata de actualizar el modelo,  no creo que se pueda poner un breakpoint.

Comment: Tienes alguna tabla que se llame EstadisticasConciliacion

Comment: sip, es correcto hay una tabla que se llama EstadisticasConciliacion

Comment: Seria bueno que tambien subas la estructura de esa tabla, porque el error que colocaste hace referencia a ella.

Comment: Seguro que esa es la estructura actualiza, por que hasta donde veo la columna EsReverso no es una llave, y el error indica de que es una llave y no puede ser nula.